# Is there a way to call: Protected Override void WndProc(ref Message m) in VB6?

Tags: vba, vb6

I am implementing an application in C#.net that is passing a message to an VB6 application.

For testing I created 2 applications both in C#.NET:- One sends message and 2nd receives the message.

The receiving application (C#.NET) makes use of the following function to catch the message:-

```
Protected Override void WndProc(ref Message m)
```

I now need to implement this receiver app in VB6.. How do we implement Protected Override void WndProc(ref Message m) in VB6? Or is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the default windows procedure is possible in VB6 and is called *Subclassing*.

In a module:

```
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Const GWL_WNDPROC As Long = (-4)
Private originalWindowProcAddr As Long

Public Sub subclassForm(hwnd As Long)
    '// replace existing windows procedure save its address
    originalWindowProcAddr = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf NewWindowProc)
End Sub

Public Function NewWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Debug.Print "received message for:", hwnd, "message:", uMsg

    '// forward message to default
    NewWindowProc = CallWindowProc(originalWindowProcAddr, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
End Function

Public Sub unSubclassForm(hwnd As Long)
    '// must tidy up by restoring the original window proc
    SetWindowLong hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, originalWindowProcAddr
End Sub
```

In the form

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   subclassForm Me.hwnd
End Sub

Private Sub form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    unSubclassForm Me.hwnd
End Sub
```

Failing to call `unSubclassForm` will crash the VB IDE, as will breaking into debug mode.

Comment: +1 but it's safer & easier to subclass like [this](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/HookXP/) in VB6. Karl Peterson usually has the best way to do anything in VB6.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this method:- 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176058/en-us

Alternate link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150118054920/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/176058

How To Pass String Data Between Applications Using SendMessage

SUMMARY
There are many ways to achieve inter-process communication using Visual Basic. Unless you establish an OLE Automation client server relationship, string data is difficult to handle cleanly. The main reason is that 32-bit applications run in a separate address space, so the address of a string in one application is not meaningful to another application in a different address space. Using the SendMessage() API function to pass a WM_COPYDATA message avoids this problem.

This article demonstrates how to pass string data from one application to another by using the SendMessage API function with the WM_COPYDATA message.

WARNING: One or more of the following functions are discussed in this article; VarPtr, VarPtrArray, VarPtrStringArray, StrPtr, ObjPtr. These functions are not supported by Microsoft Technical Support. They are not documented in the Visual Basic documentation and are provided in this Knowledge Base article "as is." Microsoft does not guarantee that they will be available in future releases of Visual Basic.

Visual Basic does not support pointers and castings in the manner of Visual C++. In order to pass string data from one Visual Basic application to another, the Unicode string must be converted to ASCII prior to passing it to the other application. The other application must then convert the ASCII string back to Unicode.

The following summarizes how to pass string data from one application to another.
Step-by-Step Example
Convert the string to a byte array using the CopyMemory() API.
Obtain the address of the byte array using the VarPtr() intrinsic function and copy the address and length of the byte array into a COPYDATASTRUCT structure.
Pass the COPYDATASTRUCT to another application using the WM_COPYDATA message, setting up the other application to receive the message.
Unpack the structure on the target system using CopyMemory(), and convert the byte array back to a string using the StrConv() intrinsic function.
The next section shows you how to create a sample program that demonstrates passing string data from one application to another.
Steps to Create the Sample
To create this sample, you create two separate projects; a sending project and a target project.

Create the target application:
Start a new Standard EXE project in Visual Basic. Form1 is created by default. This project will be your target application.
Add a Label control to Form1.
Copy the following code to the Code window of Form1:
      Private Sub Form_Load()
          gHW = Me.hWnd
          Hook
          Me.Caption = "Target"
          Me.Show
          Label1.Caption = Hex$(gHW)
      End Sub

```
  Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
      Unhook
  End Sub
```

Add a module to the project and paste the following code in the Module1 code window:
     Type COPYDATASTRUCT
              dwData As Long
              cbData As Long
              lpData As Long
      End Type

```
  Public Const GWL_WNDPROC = (-4)
  Public Const WM_COPYDATA = &H4A
  Global lpPrevWndProc As Long
  Global gHW As Long

  'Copies a block of memory from one location to another.

  Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
     (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)

  Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias _
     "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hwnd As _
     Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As _
     Long) As Long

  Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
     (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As _
     Long) As Long

  Public Sub Hook()
      lpPrevWndProc = SetWindowLong(gHW, GWL_WNDPROC, _
      AddressOf WindowProc)
      Debug.Print lpPrevWndProc
  End Sub

  Public Sub Unhook()
      Dim temp As Long
      temp = SetWindowLong(gHW, GWL_WNDPROC, lpPrevWndProc)
  End Sub

  Function WindowProc(ByVal hw As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
     ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
      If uMsg = WM_COPYDATA Then
          Call mySub(lParam)
      End If
      WindowProc = CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndProc, hw, uMsg, wParam, _
         lParam)
  End Function

  Sub mySub(lParam As Long)
      Dim cds As COPYDATASTRUCT
      Dim buf(1 To 255) As Byte

      Call CopyMemory(cds, ByVal lParam, Len(cds))

      Select Case cds.dwData
       Case 1
          Debug.Print "got a 1"
       Case 2
          Debug.Print "got a 2"
       Case 3
          Call CopyMemory(buf(1), ByVal cds.lpData, cds.cbData)
          a$ = StrConv(buf, vbUnicode)
          a$ = Left$(a$, InStr(1, a$, Chr$(0)) - 1)
          Form1.Print a$
      End Select
  End Sub
```

Save the project and minimize the Visual Basic IDE.

Create the Sending Application

Start a second instance of the Visual Basic IDE and create a new Standard EXE project in Visual Basic. Form1 is created by default.

Add a CommandButton to Form1.

Copy the following code to the Code window of Form1:
      Private Type COPYDATASTRUCT
              dwData As Long
              cbData As Long
              lpData As Long
      End Type

```
  Private Const WM_COPYDATA = &H4A

  Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias _
     "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName _
     As String) As Long

  Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias _
     "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal _
     wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

  'Copies a block of memory from one location to another.
  Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
     (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)

  Private Sub Command1_Click()
      Dim cds As COPYDATASTRUCT
      Dim ThWnd As Long
      Dim buf(1 To 255) As Byte

  ' Get the hWnd of the target application
      ThWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Target")
      a$ = "It Works!"
  ' Copy the string into a byte array, converting it to ASCII
      Call CopyMemory(buf(1), ByVal a$, Len(a$))
      cds.dwData = 3
      cds.cbData = Len(a$) + 1
      cds.lpData = VarPtr(buf(1))
      i = SendMessage(ThWnd, WM_COPYDATA, Me.hwnd, cds)
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form_Load()
  ' This gives you visibility that the target app is running
  ' and you are pointing to the correct hWnd
      Me.Caption = Hex$(FindWindow(vbNullString, "Target"))
  End Sub
```

Save the project.

Running the Sample

Restore the target application and press the F5 key to run the project. Note that the value of the hWnd displayed in the label.

Restore the sending application and press the F5 key to run the project. Verify that the hWnd in the form caption matches the hWnd in the label on the target application. Click the CommandButton and the text message should be displayed on the form of the target application.

Comment: For those coming here later: https://web.archive.org/web/20150118054920/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/176058